# how to integrate ELK with mule ESB and postregsql? Please anyone advise and provide links

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, mule-esb

I want to integrate ELK with Mule ESB and Postregsql. please provide links
I want to push logs from below servers to ELK
1.  MySQL or Postgres server – Mostly Postgres
2.  Mule ESB server
3.  NodeJS sever

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to approach this - the easiest is implement FileBeats on the mule server to consume your logs then utilize Logstash to consume the logs from your beats products.  You will need to apply a logstash filter to the mule logs and mutate them into something useful.

I would highly recommend using the ELK 6 stack.